Unsure whether this series converges or diverges
I am having difficulty with the following question regarding the convergence of a series
Suppose, $(\sum a_n) $is an absolutely convergent series, and $(\sum b_n)$ is a conditionally convergent series. Determine whether the following statement converges, diverges, or could be either. Recall for a real number $(a)$ we define
$a^+ = \begin{cases}
a & \text{if } a \geq 0, \\
0 & \text{if } a < 0,
\end{cases}
\quad \text{and} \quad
a^- = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } a > 0, \\
-a & \text{if } a \leq 0.
\end{cases}$
Does $(\sum (a_n^+b_n^-))$ converge?

You know that $|b_n|\to 0$.  So, what can you say about the magnitude of the product term?

Notice that $a_n^+\leq |a_n|$ for all $n\geq 1$, so by the direct comparison test $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^+<+\infty,$$
where we have used that the series of $a_n$ converges absolutely.
As $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n<\infty$ we must have $|b_n|\to0$ and consequently $b_n^-\to 0$ (again, because $b_n^-\leq |b_n|$).
This means there exists some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $b_n^-<1$ for all $n\geq n_0$, which in turn implies $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_n^+b_n^-\leq \displaystyle\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_n^+<\infty$$
so that $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^+b_n^-=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1} a_n^+b_n^-+\displaystyle\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_n^+b_n^-<\infty$$

As per my comment. (+1)
